# brython "Uncaught ReferenceError: brython is not defined at onload"

Tags: python, cdn, brython

hey guys and girls :) hope you can help me :)
im trying to run brython but for some reason i just get
"uncaught ReferenceError: brython is not defined
at onload" . i did try it with local installation and i tried to use the CDN source files.
and on both i get the same result.
now basically i just copied from the documentation some simple sample just to get it work :)

i did brython-cli -update
and im currently running a 3.10.3 version
in local.

but even with the CDN import script it just didnt work

im rendering the html file through flask and running flask server(maybe its just that, have no idea).

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="brython.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="brython_stdlib.js"></script>
</head>


<body onload="brython()">
  <h1>{{time_left}}</h1>

  <script type="text/python">
    from browser import document
    document <= "Hello !"
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: maybe you should use full path to javascript file - `http://yourdomain.com/path/to/brython.js` OR you should load it from some CDN server.

Comment: `flask` usually keep static files in folder `static` and you should use `src=/static/brython.js`

Comment: i'm not sure but `flask` (or maybe `djnago`) may server static files only when you run it debug mode. In normal mode it need to run with real www server like `Apache`, `Nginx` which should serve static files - because it will do it faster and using less resources.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: thanks. the problem was that the .js files wasnt in the static folder thanks.